# Is there a name for a type of database table that that forms a 0..1 relationship with another table?

Tags: database, data-modeling

Let's say I have a table called Data, and another table called ExtraData. ExtraData has a foreign key reference to Data's primary key. ExtraData is not guaranteed to have a row for every row in Data, but it can at most have one row associated to a row in Data. Is there a proper term for the type of table ExtraData is?

Bonus points on the answer if someone can point me to a resource that describes proper terminology in data modeling like this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Data** is called `Base Table` and **ExtraData** is called `Derived Table`.

Search [Wikipedia page of Weak Entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_entity) for this term.

> When sub-type relationships are rendered in a database, the super-type
>   becomes what is referred to as a base table. The sub-types are
>   considered derived tables, which correspond to weak entities.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful.

Comment: @tarun713: Happy to help.